# Selecionar data antes de fazer busca

Tags: php, datepicker, timestamp

Já tentei fazer várias coisas mas nenhuma acabou dando certo, ok vamos la.

Preciso fazer um **filtro por data** para facilitar as buscas, mesmo setando uma data específica acaba que todos os resultados são mostrados, quero pegar a data de um *timestamp* e eu estou usando `datepicker` para setar os valores, provavelmente não estou fazendo isso da forma correta.

Segue o meu código:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// conexao
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="";
$db_password="";
$db_name="";
$tabela="usuario";
$BDcoluna1="log";
$BDcoluna2="nome";
$BDcoluna3="usuario";
$BDcoluna4="email";

      mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
      mysql_select_db("$db_name");

      $query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

       $query_for_result=mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE
            $BDcoluna1 BETWEEN '".$de."%' AND '".$para."%'
            AND
            $BDcoluna2 LIKE '".$query."%'
            OR
            $BDcoluna3 LIKE '".$query."%'
            OR
            $BDcoluna4 LIKE '".$query."%'
            ");
echo "<center>
<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing=0 style=border-collapse: collapse bordercolor='#4B5AAB'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Data</th>
                <th>Analista</th>
                    <th>Solicitante</th>
                <th>Centro de Custo</th>
           <th>motivos</th>
      </tr>";
echo "<h2>Resultado da Busca</h2>";

while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{   echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' .substr($data_fetch[$BDcoluna1]. '</td>', 0,160);
echo '<td>' .substr($data_fetch[$BDcoluna2]. '</td>', 0,160);
echo '<td>' .substr($data_fetch[$BDcoluna3]. '</td>', 0,160);
echo '<td>' .substr($data_fetch[$BDcoluna4]. '</td>', 0,160);
echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: $BDcoluna1 seria sua coluna que contém as datas? Tente imprimir a query gerada antes de executá-la para ver se foi gerada corretamente.

Comment: Sim, $BDcoluna1 é minha coluna com as datas, e sim ela imprimi normalmente. ;/

Comment: Porque está usando '%' na coluna 'date'? Esse caracter para LIKE não é para consultas em string? Posta um exemplo do sql gerado por favor.

Comment: A busca por data é complementar, ao menos deveria ser, ela deveria ordenar os resultados por data para facilitar as buscas, a questão do '%' realmente acho que não está certo isso, o **LIKE** são para outros campos.

Comment: Para filtrar por data tente usar **"$BDcoluna1 BETWEEN $de AND $para"** lembrando que seu parâmetro $de/$para deve estar no formato do DB para funcionar, ex: '2014-11-11'. Para ordenar pode utilizar **"ORDER BY $BDcoluna1"**

Comment: Não deu certo, mas agradeço a ajuda ;)

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na sua query.

```
$query_for_result=mysql_query("
        SELECT * FROM $tabela WHERE
        $BDcoluna1 BETWEEN '".$de."%' AND '".$para."%'
        AND
        $BDcoluna2 LIKE '".$query."%'
        OR
        $BDcoluna3 LIKE '".$query."%'
        OR
        $BDcoluna4 LIKE '".$query."%'
        ");
```

Tente inserir sua condição `OR` entre parenteses:

```
$query_for_result=mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM {$tabela} WHERE
    $BDcoluna1 BETWEEN '{$de}' AND '{$para}'
    AND (
        $BDcoluna2 LIKE '{$query}%' OR 
        $BDcoluna3 LIKE '{$query}%' OR 
        $BDcoluna4 LIKE '{$query}%' 
    )
");
```